# Difference between .class > .class and .class .class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just want to know the difference between:

```
.class .class{
font-size:14px;
}
```

VS:

```
.class > .class{
font-size:14px;
}
```

Is the same thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, they aren't the same - the first example is a [descendant selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector), the second is a [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

---

`.class .class` will target all elements with the class `.class` which derive from any element which has the class `.class`, e.g

```
<div class="class">
 <div class="other">
    <div class="class"> This is targeted. </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

<kbd>**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9GQP/2/)**</kbd>

---

`.class > .class` will only target direct children of elements with the class `.class`, e.g

```
<div class="class">
   <div class="other">
      <div class="class">This isn't targeted.</div>
   </div> 
   <div class="class">
      <div class="class">This is targeted, as it is a direct child.</div>
   </div>    
</div>
```

<kbd>**[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/k9GQP/1/)**</kbd>